# Why am I unable to align this nav to center?

Tags: html, css

Using the following code, it cannot align itself to center, and it seems that it was the problem of FLOAT :

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a target="_parent" href="index.php" class="button">Home</a></li>
        <li><a target="_parent" href="about.html" class="button">About</a></li>
        <li><a target="_parent" href="login/reg.php" class="button">Register</a></li>
        <li><a target="_parent" href="private/" class="button">Member</a></li>
        <li><a target="_parent" href="chat.php" class="button">Chat</a></li>
        <li><a target="_parent" href="http://yo.hostei.com" class="button">URL Shortener</a></li>
        <li><a target="_parent" href="http://sql17.000webhost.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php?db=a7593238_data" class="button">Admin</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<style>
    nav {
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
    }
    ul li {
        list-style:none;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .button {
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#000000;
        padding:10px 20px;
        float:left;
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
```

However, I still need this float, else the `<li>` will be a list vertically, not horizontally.
What should I do, in my `<style>` / `CSS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `float` and add `display:inline` for `li` to make it horizontal.

```
nav {
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
    }
    ul li {
        list-style:none;
        text-align:center;
        display:inline
    }
    .button {
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#000000;
        padding:10px 20px;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wapocore/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for your kindness, but I used `display:inline-block;` instead. I will accept your answer. But if I later forgets to do so, forgive me.

Comment: Was trying your code on fiddle so no harm adding the same here.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float` for `.button` and add `display:inline-block;` for the `li`

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/8xrTH/)

CSS

```
nav {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
ul li {
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}
.button {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000000;
    padding:10px 20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
nav {
  margin:0 auto;  
    width:660px;
}
```